# NativeScript geolocation set purpose message for tracking location

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

I'm using nativescript-vue and [nativescript-geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation) plugin.

Apple doesn't approve my app because I don't specify what is the reason for geo tracking upon sending the allow request to the user (see example):
[image]

As far as I see, there is no such option in nativescript-geolocation to change that message.

Is there any other ways to change this message or perhaps there is a hidden option at nativescript-geolocation that I've missed?

Comment: I believe the reason is specified in your application's manifest, not in code. Check your build process documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the plugin ReadMe file,

> For a custom prompt message on IOS, the following keys are required:
>   [NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationalwaysandwheninuseusagedescription) (iOS 11.0+) OR
>   [NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationalwaysusagedescription?language=objc) (iOS 8.0-10.0) and
>   [NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationalwaysusagedescription?language=objc). Read more about request
>   always usage.

You will add these keys in your `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message here.</string>
```

Comment: Yup, figured this by now after @dai comment. Thanks!